# Webpack not bundling node modules imported in dependency JS files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using Webpack to bundle my ReactJS application.

**helloworld.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <h2>Hello {this.props.name}!</h2>;
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import HelloWorld from './helloworld';

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld name="World" />,
    document.getElementById('container'));
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: 'bundle.js',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /(\.js|\.jsx)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

When I run `webpack-dev-server --progress --colors` I'm getting an error in the browser **"React is not defined"** but if I import React directly in the index.js then the error not comes. **Why Webpack is not including React in the bundle if it is referenced in the helloworld.js file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well webpack only tries to bundle up the individual modules by reading the dependencies in it and resolving them to render a particular element. Now while bundling

```
ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld name="World" />,
    document.getElementById('container'));
```

ReactDOM tries to execute `React.createElement(_Helloworld2.default, { name: 'World' }), document.getElementById('app')` function which requires React as a dependency that is not present in your index.js file so it gives an error and solve the issue when you `import React` in your `index.js` file. I hope I was able to explain and my answer helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `import React from  'react';` statement. 
You will need it every time You write some JSX in a file, because it is transformed into `React.createElement(..)` function calls.