# Webpack and Node modules

Tags: webpack

I was wondering if webpack automatically bundles the files inside the node_modules folder that are being used or if there was someway to bundle them.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack not bundling node modules imported in dependency JS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218272/webpack-not-bundling-node-modules-imported-in-dependency-js-files)

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what webpack is for. However it only bundles files that have been required or imported.